# presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL dismissing immediately without playing the audio

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2, audio-player

I'm creating a watch application which records an audio and play that audio. The recorded audio is saved in the Apps Groups and I used the following code for playing the audio.

```
- (void)playAudio
{
    // Playing the audio from the url using the default controller
    [self presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:self.audioFileURL options:@{WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsAutoplayKey : @YES} completion:^(BOOL didPlayToEnd, NSTimeInterval endTime, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
    }];
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error and the player controller get dismissed immediately.

> Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=4 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (1), NSUnderlyingError=0x16daa810 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}.

Then I downloaded a sample project ([WatchKitAudioRecorder Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/WatchKitAudioRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html)) from Apple WatchOS Developer library but they are also having the same issue. I don't know why this is not working even in Apple Sample code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that the data is not writing to the url path. Also should be written in the following path: Library/Caches/filename.extension
Here is a sample code, which may help someone.

```
- (void)writeAudioToAppGroupsWithData:(NSData *)audioData
{
    // Writing the audio data to the App Groups
    NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER];
    containerURL = [containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:DIRECTORY_PATH]];
    [audioData writeToURL:containerURL atomically:YES];
}
```

In this case make sure that your **DIRECTORY_PATH** is **Library/Caches/filename.extension**. Eg: Library/Caches/Audio.mp3